# We are getting a "18446744073709551615" response from nginx instead of proper response code

Tags: nginx

Intermittently the nginx responds with code "18446744073709551615" instead of proper http code.
The down stream server however responds with 200 OK
If the nginx is restarted the issue goes away. How can I fix this issue permanently ?

Log message:

"127.0.0.1" "-" "-" [09/Nov/2020:13:37:16 +0000] "GET ///v1/healthcheck HTTP/1.1" "18446744073709551615" "0" "-" "curl/7.29.0" "0" "98" "/v1/healthcheck" "localonly" "-" "localonly" "9999" "0.000" "-" "-" "-" "-" "-" "-" "-" "-" "-" "-"

Comment: Could you please give us more details, like the full log message ?

Comment: edited the actual question with log message

Comment: It's probably relevant that your response is `2^64 - 1` -- i.e., 64 bits worth of 1s.

Comment: That's not a programming question, hence off-topic here.

Comment: How are the logs being generated? Is there a process returning a `-1` exit code that's later being parsed as a 64-bit _unsigned_ integer?

Comment: the customer request first hits the ngnix which in turn hits the application server, the application server returns a 200 OK, however the ngnix returns above unknown code, this is were we see this log in access.log of nginx